# "Revive" vs "survive"

Tags: differences

What's the difference between *revive* and *survive*?

> Revive: restore to life or consciousness.
>
> Survive: remain alive after the death of (a particular person).

The meanings don't seem so different to me. Is it just another word for the other, or is there a subtle  difference?

Comment: The difference is crystal clear.

Comment: @Centaurus My question is not off-topic, and if it was crystal clear for me, I wouldn't ask. don't abuse commenting privilege for taunting people who know less than you

Comment: No offense meant, ali, but it **is** crystal clear.  You're welcome here but you should have posted your question at English Language Learners http://ell.stackexchange.com/   which is the Stack Exchange site for  speakers of other languages learning English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODO provides the following examples with the definitions:

> **Revive** *verb*
> 1 Restore to life or consciousness: *both men collapsed, but were revived*
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/revive)
>
> **Survive** *verb*
> 1.2 [with object] Remain alive after the death of (a particular person): *he was survived by his wife and six children*
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/survive)

As the examples illustrate, the sense of *revive* is that the restored person is the one who died or lost consciousness, while the person who *survived* someone else's death is different from the person who died.

In the dictionary's examples, men who collapsed were the same people who were *revived*, while the dead husband was *survived* by his wife (or more properly, widow) and six children. Note that the dead husband was not survived by himself.

This use of *survive* is different from that used in sentences like "He survived a fall", where the person who experienced an event did not die.

You ask:

> The meaning[s] don't seem so much different for me. Is it just another word for the other, or there is a subtle difference?

The main difference between the notions of revival and survival is that *revival* requires the loss of whatever was subsequently restored, while *survival* requires its continuity. So if a person died and was later restored to life, they can be said to have been *revived*, but strictly-speaking, they cannot be said to have *survived*.

Answer (score 2):

[Vive](https://www.wordnik.com/words/vive) is a rare word and it basically means [Lively](https://www.wordnik.com/words/lively), probably in the sense of animated or Full of Life-Energy, according to the 1914 [Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia](http://www.global-language.com/century/).

Survive uses the [Sur-](http://www.tfd.com/sur-)<sup>1</sup> prefix which means over, hence we use Sur- to signified that we lived over, or rather beyond a certain point and so [survive](https://1828.mshaffer.com/survive) means:

> 1. To outlive; to live beyond the life of another; as,the wife survives her husband; or a husband survives his wife.

A woman who survives her husband becomes a [widow](https://1828.mshaffer.com/survive):

> WIDOW, n. [L. See Wide.] A woman who has lost her husband by death. Luke 2.
>
> Widows chamber, in London, the apparel and furniture of the bed-chamber of the widow of a freeman, to which she is entitled.
>
> ---
>
> [The American Dictionary of the English Language by Noah Webster, 1828](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/widow)

So an exemplary sentence may be:

> "The longer a widow survives her husband, the more diluted financial position becomes." — The [Harvard women's law journal, Volumes 1-6, page 43, 1978](https://books.google.com/books?id=BN9MAQAAIAAJ&q=%22A+widow+survives+her+husband%22&dq=%22A+widow+survives+her+husband%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLutyI48LOAhUD5mMKHYuxA2sQ6AEIKTAC)

However, it would be more common for [Survive](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2365651) to be used in another sense, which essentially means to escape death:

> 2. To outlive any thing else; to live beyond any event. Who would wish to survive the ruin of his country? Many men survive their usefulness or the regular exercise of their reason.
>
> ---
>
> [The American Dictionary of the English Language, written by Noah Webster](http://edl.byu.edu/webstersearchresults.php?wq=survive&x=0&y=0)

---

The [Re-](http://www.tfd.com/re-)<sup>2</sup> prefix means again, hence [revive](https://1828.mshaffer.com/d/word/revive) means becoming lively or lifelike again, usually after you lose all liveliness after death:

> 1. To return to life; to recover life.
>
> The soul of the child came into him again, and he revived. 1 [Kings 17:22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%2017:22).
>
> ---
>
> [The American Dictionary of the English Language, written by Noah Webster in 1828.](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/revive)

So an exemplary sentence is "The phoenix: or Prelacy revived from the Ashes of its *Funeral*, etc." — [A Bibliography of Works Relating to Dunfermline and the West of Fife, by Erskine Beveridge, page 52 1901](https://books.google.com/books?id=OmkLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA52&dq=the+phoenix+revived+from+the+ashes&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0hczn58LOAhUFax4KHVaSBZMQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=the%20phoenix%20revived%20from%20the%20ashes&f=false)

> [Phoenix](http://dictionary.babylon-software.com/phoenix/#): Same as Phenix.
>
> ---
>
> [Phenix](https://1828.mshaffer.com/d/word/phenix): A bird fabled to exist single, to be consumed by fire by its own act, and to rise again from its ashes. Hence, an emblem of immortality.
>
> ---
>
> [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary 1913](http://www.bibliomania.com/2/3/257/frameset.html)

---

**See also:**

<sup>1</sup> The American Heritage Dictionary Fifth Edition's [Sur-](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Sur-&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) entry

<sup>2</sup> The American Heritage Dictionary Fifth Edition's [Re-](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Re-&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) Entry